# perl split behaviour differences?

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I installed active perl same version on windows XP and windows 7.

I have found that on windows XP and ubuntu split will return empty array elements, but on windows 7 it won't. For example:

```
my @array;
my $item = "test,,,,";
@array = split(/,/,$item);
print $#array;
```

will print 4 and the array will have 3 empty elements, but on windows 7 it always prints 0 and has only 1 element. Does anyone know why this happens and what I should be using to make the perl script more portable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the Windows 7 version is correct:

> By default, empty leading fields are
>   preserved, and empty trailing ones are
>   deleted. (If all fields are empty,
>   they are considered to be trailing.)

So if you split e.g. `",,,test,,,,"` then your example should print `3`. (Tested with 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.)

Comment: Yes, and moreover, `print $#{[ split(/,/, ",,,test,,,,", -1) ]};` should always print `7`.

Comment: I found that there was actually a \r after the last comma (which wasn't printing out as anything). It was a problem relating to $/ which is different on different systems.